# Rewrite redirecting first to cached content

Tags: caching, mod-rewrite

I tried many combinations but none works. I trying to write rewrite rule which:

1. Assume URL of http://example.com/project/big_bunny
2. When user visit site rewrite first try to read file /cache/project/big_bunny.html but only if there is no any get or post data
3. If there is no cache rewrite process standard router rule: index.php?_rt=$1 [L,QSA]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Check the cache, and rewrite if file exists
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^POST [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ /cache%{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]

# If URI doesn't start with /cache/, it wasn't cached so rewrite to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cache/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Check if using POST method
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^POST
# Check if already rewrote to cache
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cache
# Check if cache exists
RewriteCond /cache%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
# Check if contains any GET query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
# Do the rewrite
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /cache/$1.html [L]

# Check if already rewrote to cache
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cache
RewriteRule ^/(.*) index.php?_rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```